# Filling missing values with monthly mean

Tags: r, date

I have monthly time series data for about 10 years. The problems is that there are few missing values(NA) within the series.
My aim is to fill the missing values with the mean of all the particular months in the series.
For example. I have missing value for July 1994 (and other months as well), i want to replace this missing value with  the mean of all other July months in the series.
The series is as shown below.

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("1993-12-01"), as.Date("2005-05-01"), by = "1 month")

value <- c(2.20000, 0.70000, 2.80000, 0.80000,1.20000, 1.50000, 0.90000 ,     NA, 0.80000, 1.70000, 2.40000,
 1.60000, 4.00000, 4.40000, 2.50000, 1.10000, 2.40000, 1.10000, 3.70000, 6.40000, 7.00000, 2.90000,
  3.00000, 3.60000, 4.90000,      NA, 4.90000, 0.70000, 0.3000, 0.70000 ,0.37000,0.20000, 0.05000,
  0.35000, 0.05000, 2.50000, 0.08000, 0.12000, 2.53000, 2.49000, 2.04000, 2.92000 0.27000 0.33000,
 0.10000, 0.36000, 2.32000, 0.1900, 0.2300, 0.18000, 0.28000, 0.19500, 0.07300, 0.65000,0.30000)
```

The vector value is just a extract from the series and not the whole series.

so does any one have any idea as to how can this be achieved?

Comment: The Date and value vectors are not the same length and there are syntax errors due to missing commas. Please fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked a bit your initial data to be able to make a data frame with your two columns:

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("1993-12-01"), as.Date("1998-06-01"), by = "1 month")

value <- c(2.20000, 0.70000, 2.80000, 0.80000, 1.20000, 1.50000, 0.90000,      NA, 0.80000, 1.70000, 2.40000,
           1.60000, 4.00000, 4.40000, 2.50000, 1.10000, 2.40000, 1.10000, 3.70000, 6.40000, 7.00000, 2.90000,
           3.00000, 3.60000, 4.90000,      NA, 4.90000, 0.70000, 0.30000, 0.70000 ,0.37000, 0.20000, 0.05000,
           0.35000, 0.05000, 2.50000, 0.08000, 0.12000, 2.53000, 2.49000, 2.04000, 2.92000, 0.27000, 0.33000,
           0.10000, 0.36000, 2.32000, 0.19000, 0.23000, 0.18000, 0.28000, 0.19500, 0.07300, 0.65000, 0.30000)

mydf <- data.frame(Date, value)

# Get the month and add it as a column
mydf$month <- months(mydf$Date)

# Calculate the average by month
avg_by_month <- with(mydf, aggregate(value, by=list(month=month), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE))

# Merge averaged values to the data frame
mydf2 <- merge(x = mydf, y = avg_by_month, by = "month")

# Recuperate the average where needed
mydf2$value[is.na(mydf2$value)] <- mydf2$x[is.na(mydf2$value)]

# Discard average if not needed anymore
mydf2$x <- NULL
```

Comment: Hello sir, Thank you so much.  avg_by_ month perfectly works but i encountered error in mydf2. The error is as:"Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column". I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: Ok so if this is at the `merge` step, you must ensure `"month"` is an actual column name in both `mydf` and `avg_by_month` and that both are stored as the same data type.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Works perfectly. :) . Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sure, glad to help! :)

Comment: i am really sorry, though the above mentioned process works, i have to repeatedly do for the other variables. Is there a way to recuperate the average for  all the variables in the series at one go?.  The series is as shown: Observations: 138    Variables: 30 $ Sl.no <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,... $ Date <date> 1993-12-01, 1994-01-01, 1994-... $ Month <fctr> December, January, February, ... $ Value1 <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 30.0, 35.5, ... $ Value2 <dbl> 16.0, 15.5, 18.5, 24.0, 27.0, ... $Value3 and so on

Comment: There are several ways you can go about this. You could wrap it up in a function that you could call as many times as there are columns, or through `lapply`. Or maybe use one of the R packages dealing specifically with data imputation. This would deserve a new question on the forum though.

Comment: Ok, finally found it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this q - [R: Replacing NA values by mean of hour with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336122/r-replacing-na-values-by-mean-of-hour-with-dplyr)

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("1993-12-01"), as.Date("2005-05-01"), by = "1 month")
# generate random data
value <- runif(length(Date))
# make some NULLs
value[runif(3,min=1,max=length(value))] <- NA

df <- data.frame(Date=Date,value=value)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

out <- df %>% 
  mutate(Month=month(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate(monthly_average = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE),
           new_value= replace(value, is.na(value), mean(value, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Comment: Hello sir, Thank you for your effort. However i encountered error as "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "values" is missing, with no default."  I do not know what the problem is.  Hoping to hear from you soon.

Comment: @VaskerSharma - The code snippet above works for me, so I assume you're getting that error when you try to apply it to your dataframe. It'd be easier to solve if you add the output of `dput(head(df))` to your Q.

Comment: This is the glimpse of data frame which contains multivariate series: Observations: 138 Variables: 30 $ Sl.no <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,... $ Date <date> 1993-12-01, 1994-01-01, 1994-... $ Month <fctr> December, January, February, ... $ Value1 <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 30.0, 35.5, ... $ Value2 <dbl> 16.0, 15.5, 18.5, 24.0, 27.0, ... $Value3. @Jason

Comment: @VaskerSharma - I'm not able to reproduce the error you're reporting above. My guess is that it's an issue with column names. In the section producing `out`, `value` in all cases should be the name of a column you want to impute for (e.g. `Value1` in your glimpse).

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data has not same length, therefore I created some. Approach is to group by month and, if missing, calculate mean. If you have a trend in your data you might want something different, but this should do what you asked for:

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("1993-12-01"), as.Date("2005-05-01"), by = "1 month")
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date = Date, 
                 value = rnorm(n = length(Date)))
# Add 10% missing data:
df$value[sample(x = seq_len(nrow(df)), size = nrow(df)/10)] <- NA

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  # group by month:
  group_by(month = format(date, "%m")) %>% 
  # replace with mean, if missing:
  mutate(value_complete = ifelse(is.na(value), mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), value))
```

Comment: hello sir, actually i have multi variate series, as shown : Observations: 138
Variables: 30
$ Sl.no                         <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,...
$ Date                          <date> 1993-12-01, 1994-01-01, 1994-...
$ Month                         <fctr> December, January, February, ...
$ Value1                       <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 30.0, 35.5, ...
$ Value2                      <dbl> 16.0, 15.5, 18.5, 24.0, 27.0, ...
$Value3 and so on
I have encountered error as: " Column `value_complete` must be length 12 (the group size) or one, not 3450".

Comment: @VaskerSharma If you have a multivariate series, please, post a *new* question with a [mcve] which reflects the multivariate property. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution which updates only `NA` values and avoids to append a `month` column:

```
library(data.table)
avg_by_month <- setDT(DT)[, mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), by = month(date)]
DT[is.na(value), value := avg_by_month[month == .BY, V1], by = month(date)]
```

The "trick" here is, to group the rows which contain `NA` values by `month(date)` and to use the grouping variable `.BY` to lookup the monthly average.

#### Reproducible example

The OP has provided `value` with two `NA` values. These are used but a third value is set to `NA` to have a better test case:

```
value <- c(2.20000,      NA, 2.80000, 0.80000, 1.20000, 1.50000, 0.90000,      NA, 0.80000, 1.70000, 2.40000,
           1.60000, 4.00000, 4.40000, 2.50000, 1.10000, 2.40000, 1.10000, 3.70000, 6.40000, 7.00000, 2.90000,
           3.00000, 3.60000, 4.90000,      NA, 4.90000, 0.70000, 0.30000, 0.70000, 0.37000, 0.20000, 0.05000,
           0.35000, 0.05000, 2.50000, 0.08000, 0.12000, 2.53000, 2.49000, 2.04000, 2.92000, 0.27000, 0.33000,
           0.10000, 0.36000, 2.32000, 0.19000, 0.23000, 0.18000, 0.28000, 0.19500, 0.07300, 0.65000, 0.30000)
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
  value,
  date = seq(as.Date("1993-12-01"), length.out = length(value), by = "1 month"))

# find indices of NA values
na_idx <- DT[is.na(value), which = TRUE]
DT[na_idx]
```

> ```
>    value       date
> 1:    NA 1994-01-01
> 2:    NA 1994-07-01
> 3:    NA 1996-01-01
> ```

```
avg_by_month <- setDT(DT)[, mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), by = month(date)]
DT[is.na(value), value := avg_by_month[month == .BY, V1], by = month(date)]

DT[na_idx]
```

> ```
>       value       date
> 1: 1.566667 1994-01-01
> 2: 2.310000 1994-07-01
> 3: 1.566667 1996-01-01
> ```